# findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock not entering the "Block"

Tags: swift, parse-platform

My code is something like following, and what I don't understood is why the code after `Void in` never runs? I did tried to debug but it appears `Block` never gets executed.

By the way, query will return empty.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "LastId")
query.whereKey("UserId", equalTo: opUserIdList[i])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
    if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {
            object.setValue(self.opLastIdChangedToList[i], forKey: "lastId")
            object.saveInBackground()
        }
    } else {
        let newLine = PFObject(className: "LastId")
        newLine["lastId"] = self.opLastIdChangedToList[i]
        newLine["userIdself."] = self.opUserIdList[i]
        newLine.saveInBackground()
    }
})
//rest of the code
```

Comment: Give more context about how this is run and how you know it starts

Comment: when i debug the code it runs query. query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock and then jumps to //rest of the code.

Comment: Because it's async? Try to put a breakpoint inside the block, and wait your app to go into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the block of code after `Void in` is the closure. To say in simple that is a pointer to a function containing the code (code block) that is executed  later, after the completion of the parent function in which it was called.

Try reading the documentation to better understand how to work with it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94

Comment: thank you for the answer. Now I see what was going on. By the way, as the closure is being executed later async, i get error array index out of range because i (index for for loop) becomes greater thank the count of array. Is there any easy solution for this or do I have to use a sync function?(findObjects in this case)

Comment: @ErkanA Because of a `closure can capture constants and variables from the surrounding context in which it is defined`, your `i` index when closure was called not equal to `i` index when you call `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`. To fix this, you can save current `i` value to some constant `let currentIndex = i` before calling the `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` and inside closure work with it constant value: `object.setValue(self.opLastIdChangedToList[currentIndex], forKey: "lastId")`